# Handling a checkBox where selection state is stored as part of the class value

Tags: java, webdriver

> unchecked Box

```
<input data-track-event="my_account" data-track-action="newsletter-unselect" data-track-data="Page[My Account]|<-vertical->|<-horizontal->|<-rel_vertical->|<-rel_horizontal->|Newsletters|Business - checkbox|Pos[3:8]|" type="checkbox" name="newsletters[]" id="f-newsletters-business" value="business" class="tick-a">
```

> checkedBox

```
<input data-track-event="my_account" data-track-action="newsletter-unselect" data-track-data="Page[My Account]|<-vertical->|<-horizontal->|<-rel_vertical->|<-rel_horizontal->|Newsletters|Style - checkbox|Pos[5:8]|" type="checkbox" name="newsletters[]" id="f-newsletters-independent_woman" value="independent_woman" class="tick-a" checked="">
```

> my Code

```
public void checkboxIsSelected(By by, String text) {
    try {
        String checkBoxClass = driver.findElement(by).getAttribute("class");            

        if (checkBoxClass.contains("tick-a checked")) {
            log.log("CheckBox is already selected.... Move On.");                                           
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log("CheckBox NOT checked... Pls Select to avail of: " + text);
        driver.findElement(by).click();
        log.log("CheckBox selected..... continue.");    
    }
}
```

please i need to check if the check box is checked or not,. Based on the research i made, i discovered that there are some common web-app jQueries that are very similar to JavaScript libraries, where selection state are stored as part of the class value.... thereby making it difficult to use the isSelected(). Have tried all possible effort but its either the method un-checks the already checkbox or throws an error.
Am using the getAttribute() to get the class and check if it contains define text but as you can see, the class has a predefined text(tick-a) and changes to ((tick-a) checked) when the box is checked. that's the point am having the difficulty.
Will appreciate an help rendered. Have also checked related topics but none helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean here but looking at your unchecked and checked code snippets the 'checked' class is not being added, `class="tick-a"`. So `checkBoxClass.contains("tick-a checked")` will never be true.

Comment: Tanx for the response. maybe am doing it wrong. ABove is the javascript snippet. Its obvious that the isSelected wont work for the checkbox because the value is only stored as part of the class value. Now the question is, how do i check if the check box is selected or not.? Rather than writing an else i added that part in the catch. Should i remove the try ctach and add al else statement?

Comment: **Modified Code**     `public void checkboxIsSelected(By by, String text) throws Exception {  
    
  boolean isCheck = driver.findElement(by).isSelected();
   if (!isCheck) {
    log.log("CheckBox NOT checked... Pls Select to avail of: " + text);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.findElement(by).click();
    log.log("CheckBox selected..... continue.");
              
   }else
   {
    log.log("CheckBox is already selected.... Move On.");
   }
  
 }`  **but this code is selecting the uncelected checkbox and deselecting the already selected checkbox.**

Answer (score 0):

> Just a quick update.... figured the solution out myself. After taking a proper look at the javascript, i discovered i was pointing to the wrong element. WOrking code below.

```
public void checkboxIsSelected(By by, String text) {

        try {
            if (!driver.findElement(by).isSelected()) {                 
                log.log("CheckBox NOT checked... Pls Select to avail of: " + text);
                JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(by));
                log.log("checkBox clicked..... Move On.");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                //driver.findElement(by).click();
            }else
            {
                log.log("CheckBox is ALREADY selected.... Move On.");                   
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

> Tanx